# Does the system raise an intent event when clipboard is updating?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-broadcast

I'm going to create a `BroadcastReceiver` which use to **monitoring Clipboard**, but I can't find an available `Intent-Filiter` action, 
Do we have this intent?

Comment: check out this class : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ClipboardManager.html there is ClipboardManager.OnPrimaryClipChangedListener to listen to clipboard changes

Comment: I know this class, but my requirement is that if my app is not running in foreground, I can't use ClipboardManager.OnPrimaryClipChangedListener do it, unless you ceate a service.